# How to keep redux saga running when app in background react native

Tags: react-native, background-process, redux-saga

Is there anyway to keep saga (call api) running when app in background? I am using RN 0.61.5. Sorry I couldn't give any code since I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: you might want to check https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate

Comment: @SDushan I know about appstate. But, idk what I have to do to keep the saga run when app not active/in background.